# What is the proper way to execute a make command within a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to build a shell script to execute the following two commands, but the shell complains that it does not know about the parameters clean or reload.

```
    make -f '/home/ec2-user/infx/infx.mak' clean
    make -f '/home/ec2-user/infx/infx.mak' reload > '/home/ec2-user/infx/mylog.txt' 2>&1
```

I would like to make a variable out of the directory as well, but when trying to concat the directory and infx.mak I am having even more issues.

Thanks for your help

Code and Errors:

```
    echo "Cleaning Project"
    make -f '/home/ec2-user/infx/infx.mak' clean
    echo "Making Project"
    make -f '/home/ec2-user/infx/infx.mak' reload > '/home/ec2-user/infx/mylog.txt' 2>&1
    srcdir='/home/ec2-user/infx'
    srcmak='/infx.mak'
    echo "$srcmak$srcdir"
    exit 0

    [ec2-user@ip infx]$ sudo ./reload.sh
    '.  Stop. No rule to make target `clean
    : ambiguous redirect 1
    /home/ec2-user/infx
```

Comment: Post the code you tried for making the dir. a variable, and post the _exact_ error messages.

Comment: What you are doing seems ok on the surface.  You'll need to give more detail.  What error are you getting?

Comment: Perhaps your `infx.mak` file don't contain rules for `clean` or `reload` targets. I would suggest using `remake` to debug it.

Comment: Basile since I created the file, and have used it without the script, it indeed works. @tripleee, if you post this as an answer I will accepted it because it worked like a charm. My notepad++ application has a unix line feeds option.

Comment: Did so, and removed my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message looks like you have DOS line endings in your script. Try `dos2unix` or `tr -d '\015'` to fix it. (Google for a bit if you need help; this is a very common problem.)